# Spring MVC: get content negotiation result in a @ExceptionHandler

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to write an `@ExceptionHandler` so JSON requests will get an error response in JSON as well. For non-JSON requests, I want the servlet container to send its default HTML response.

To do this, I'll need to do some content negotiation. Spring MVC handles it for normal requests via annotations, but no such annotation is available for `@ExceptionHandler`s.

I am wondering how can I programmatically call the content negotiation code?

Comment: Sounds tricky, but you could possibly create custom filter add it after springSecurityFilterChain. Then based on request content you could modify response content.

Comment: In the first paragraph you describe that you want to have a fixed return type (two actually). But the question is "get content negotiation result", which could be something other than JSON or HTML. You only need to check if the `Content-Type` header is `application/json` (or a variant). Then it's a JSON request and you return a JSON response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently, content negotiation happens after the error handler is called, so I have to do most of the heavy lifting myself.

The method to use is [`ContentNegotiationManager.resolveMediaTypes()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/accept/ContentNegotiationManager.html#resolveMediaTypes-org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest-), which gives a list of types that one will have to go through and make a decision.

An example of how to do this can be found the source of [ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.getMediaTypes()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.html#getMediaTypes-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-)